# Adding a header below the ribbon

Tags: ribbon, branding

I want to know if there is a way to add a header right below the ribbon?

I tried to edit and add a webpart in SharePoint Designer but didnt have any success. The header would need to sit below the ribbon, and above the banner. Thanks!